# Saving object property to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, object, javascript-objects

I have a problem with objects (actually property of them) and variables.
Here is the situation:

```js
var mainLANG = ???;

if(words[i].pol == wordToCheck){
      if(words[i].eng == wordTyped){
        correct = true;
        update_counter('.goodWords', '+', 1);
        update_counter('.allWords', '-', 1);
        elementToRemove = i;
      }else {
        update_counter('.badWords', '+', 1);
      }
```

Now, I have attributes like pol and eng inserted statically (this attributes will be changing) [ pol to eng and eng to pol - triggered by some event ]. I had an idea to declare a variable which can store information about lang (e.g. Now mainLANG is pol - after event is for example eng). What should I typed to mainLANG and how to replace word "pol". I want word 'pol' replaced by value of mainLANG was reffered to mainLANG.

Maybe a little less sophisticated (example):

```
var mainLANG = pol;
if(words[i].mainLANG .... - Error... unexpected property

var mainLANG = 'pol'
if(words[i].mainLANG .... - Another error, don't even remember its content.
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: please add all missing variables as well.

Comment: mainLANG is not a property of words[i], but a variable instead

Comment: Also please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @marvel308: I know mainLANG is variable, strictly speaking I want properties of words[i] to be dynamic :) (One time - pol, another time eng)

Answer (score 1):

I've made a setup that I think does what you're asking for.

```js
let
  // Variable to keep track of the current language.
  currentLang;
  
const
  // Mapping for a language to its code.
  languages = {
    enligh: 'eng',
    polish: 'pol'
  },
  // Scores object.
  scores = {
    goodWords: 0,
    badWords: 0,
    allWords: 2
  },
  // The words with their translation per language.
  words = [
    {
      [languages.polish]: 'A',
      [languages.english]: 'Aa'
    },
    {
      [languages.polish]: 'B',
      [languages.english]: 'Bb'
    },
    { 
      [languages.polish]: 'C',
      [languages.english]: 'Cc'
    }
  ];


/**
 * Checks if a word is valid in the current language.
 *
 * @param {Object} translations  An object with properties per language code with the right translation.
 * @param {String} word          The word as typed by the user, needs to be checked against the proper translation.
 *
 * @returns {Boolean} The method returns true when the typed word matches the translation for the current language; otherwise false.
 */
function checkWord(translations, word) {
  // Check if the word matches the translation for the current language.
  if (translations[currentLang] === word) {
    // Update the score counters.
    scores.goodWords++;
    scores.allWords--;
    
    // Return true, the word matches.
    return true;
  }
  
  // Update the score counters.
  scores.badWords++;
  // Return false, the word doesn't match the translation.
  return false;
}


// Set the current language to Polish.
currentLang = languages.polish;
console.log(`Is "A" a valid Polish word: ${checkWord(words[0], 'A')}`);
console.log(`Is "Aa" a valid Polish word: ${checkWord(words[0], 'Aa')}`);

// Set the current language to English.
currentLang = languages.english;
console.log(`Is "A" a valid English word: ${checkWord(words[0], 'A')}`);
console.log(`Is "Aa" a valid English word: ${checkWord(words[0], 'Aa')}`);
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Great, glad to have been of help!

Comment: Don’t forget to accept the answer if it answered your question.